# Is there a rule concerning the offloading of a missing passenger's baggage?

Tags: iata

Is there an International Rule under which the baggage of a passenger is offloaded in the case that he/she fails to report at the departure gate 15 minutes before boarding time?

Comment: VTR.  The OP posted this question as an answer on the question marked as duplicate.  The deletion comment requests that they ask a separate question as they have done here, only for it to be closed as a duplicate.  The answers to that question do not answer the question posed here which is specifically asking about regulations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is baggage always offloaded when a passenger does not travel?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23097/is-baggage-always-offloaded-when-a-passenger-does-not-travel)

Answer (score 3):

[This question was covered over on travel.stackexchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65939/do-they-have-to-take-checked-suitcase-off-the-airplane-if-passenger-does-not-sh) and seems like there is a European reg on it.

> In Europe, the question is covered by [Regulation EC 300/2008](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:02008R0300-20100201&rid=1). Annex I,
>   section 5.3 reads
>
> Baggage reconciliation
>
> > Each item of hold baggage shall be identified as accompanied or
> >     unaccompanied. Unaccompanied hold baggage shall not be transported,
> >     unless that baggage has been either separated due to factors beyond
> >     the passenger’s control or subjected to appropriate security controls.

I cant find any hard regulations but there seems to be [some discussions floating around that would imply](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1902118) a domestic US flight may depart with your bags and without you here in the states.

I can speak from experience while on a flight departing CDG for DUB the plane was held to remove a bag that belonged to a passenger that decided to take a different flight.